# PHP Redirect without encoding URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, urlencode, url-encoding, urldecode

I have a codeigniter app that has an authentication system. Sometimes a user will get logged out and they will get forwarded to `site.com/login?redir=feature/9+1/abc`. Upon logging in they should get forwarded to `site.com/feature/9+1/abc`

The problem arises when the user is forwarded: the `+` in the URL is changed to `%20`. `%` is a disallowed URL character so my users sees an error message saying an invalid character is in the URL. Even if I add `%` to the list of allowed characters `site.com/feature/9%201/abc` is not the same as `site.com/feature/9+1/abc` and the user sees a 404 error.

Is there there a way I can forward users using PHP to `/feature/9+1/abc` instead of `/feature/9%201/abc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify login url to `site.com/login?redir=feature/9%2B1/abc`. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

it may be useful for you as it worked for me

try urlencode function http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php in the time of sending and to fetch use urldecode function